# ContactPicker.PickSingleContactAsync Windows 8 C# usage

Tags: c#, asynchronous, contacts, windows-8

Could someone give me an example of how to use the ContactPicker.PickSingleContactAsync() functionality correctly in Windows 8 ASync programming, i've tried the following code below and I don't seem to be able to retrieve the results, let alone proceed. the JavaScript example is a bit vague and I don't understand JavaScript code. I'm new to ASync programming in C# as well

```
ContactPicker cp = new ContactPicker();
ContactInformation ci;
Task<ContactInformation> task = cp.PickSingleContactAsync() as Task<ContactInformation>;
await task;
```

How do I proceed to get results into 'ci' ? additionally, how do I ensure I get only contacts with phone numbers to pick from?

Comment: just this might work

IAsyncOperation<ContactInformation> task = cp.PickSingleContactAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ContactPicker cp = new ContactPicker();
ContactInformation ci = await cp.PickSingleContactAsync();
```

You can't `as`-cast WinRT asynchronous method results to `Task<T>`, because they're (probably) not `Task<T>`. Either `await` them directly (as above) or use the `StartAsTask` extension method:

```
ContactPicker cp = new ContactPicker();
Task<ContactInformation> ciTask = cp.PickSingleContactAsync().StartAsTask();
ContactInformation ci = await ciTask;
```